# On selfinjectivity of Hopf algebras

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

Any group algebra $kG$ of a finite group is selfinjective. More generally [Gentile](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-023-02/S0002-9939-1969-0245693-X/S0002-9939-1969-0245693-X.pdf)
 proves that for a group ring $RG$ with $R$ commutative and torsion free as a $\Bbb Z$-module, $RG$ is selfinjective if and only if $G$ is finite and $R$ is selfinjective.

Any group ring is a Hopf algebra, and a finite-dimensional cocommutative Hopf algebra over a field is selfinjective. Is there a generalization of this result in the same spirit as the result of Gentile? (Or in greater generality, see the comments.)

Comment: Any group algebra of a *finite group* over a field is self-injective. More generally, $R[G]$ is right (left) self-injective iff $G$ is finite and $R$ is right (left) self-injective.  (A proof of this in print is quite hard to find, but I convinced myself it exists by piecing things together a long time ago.)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add the condition that $G$ should be finite. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

Finite dimensional algebras have integrals, and using one you can show selfinjectivity at once —in fact, they are Frobenius.

See for example the *Lectures on Hopf algebras* by Schneider, which Google will find for you, or Susan Montgomery's book in Hopf algebras.

Comment: I am not sure whether Schneider works over a field or not (he said 'eventually' it will be over a field.) I assume your answer only holds over fields?